# Change order of integration when boundary is implicit function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to change the order of integration of

$$\int^{2a}_{0}\left( \int^{\sqrt{2ax}}_{\sqrt{2ax-x^{2}}} f(x,y) dy \right) dx $$

but I'm not sure how to express the lower boundary for y in terms of x.

Thank you.

SOLUTION ~ So here is my final solution:
$$\left( \int^{a}_{0} \int^{a-\sqrt{a^{2}-y^{2}}}_{\frac{y^{2}}{2a}}+\int^{a}_{0} \int^{2a}_{a+\sqrt{a^{2}-y^{2}}}+\int^{2a}_{a} \int^{2a}_{\frac{y^{2}}{2a}}\right) f(x,y) dx dy$$

I hope it's correct and thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: *draw* the integration limits and you will *see*.

Comment: I did, but still don't know how to express the curve in terms of x=f(y)

Comment: It is difficult to change the order of integration and stay with one integral. If you draw the region you will see that it is easier to split it into three regions first: upper, lower-left, and lower-right.

Comment: @RoryDaulton yes I did split it in three integrals, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$y = \sqrt{2ax}\implies x =y^2/2a$$
$$y = \sqrt{2ax-x^2}\implies y^2 = 2ax-x^2\implies \cdots$$
(second degree equation)

Comment: so x=a +/- sqrt(a^2-y^2)? and since y=0 -> x=0 no matter what a, I just take a-sqrt(a^2-y^2)? Alright thank you so much :D

Comment: @srmico, you will need *both* branches. *Do* the drawing

Comment: Yep, I realized that. I can solve the problem now. Thanks.